# jupyter notebook is not opening in the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[The image of error I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n798W.png)

Please help me.

Comment: Please include the error as text within the question - this helps others finding this Q/A using arbitrary search engines. Also see [ask] again. I had flagged this question with `unclear what you are asking, should be closed` but now retracted that flag as you got an answer and maybe the flag was a bad decision by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not enough information regarding the steps you took before getting the error. I have tested to create a `Jupyter notebook` both in `VM Instance` and in `Google Cloud shell`. Try one of the methods below:

For `VM Instance`:

1. Update the current packages executing `sudo apt update`
2. Install `pip` and Python header files, because they are used by some Jupyter's dependencies. Execute `sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev`
3. Upgrade `pip` by executing `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`
4. Install virtual environment by executing `sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv`
5. Create a virtual environment with `virtualenv VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME`
6. Activate the virtual environment with `source VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/activate`
7. Install Jupyter by executing `pip install jupyter`
8. Run Jupyter Notebook with local host tag as ip: `jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1`
9. After that a link will be generated and when you click on it, the Browser will show you the `Home` for `Jupyter Notebook`.

For `Google Cloud Shell` the procedure is the same with the `VM Instance` one, but skip the first 4 steps.

1. Create a virtual environment with `virtualenv VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME`
2. Activate the virtual environment with `source VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/activate`
3. Install Jupyter by executing `pip install jupyter`
4. Run Jupyter Notebook with local host tag as ip: `jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1`
5. After that a link will be generated and when you click on it, the Browser will show you the `Home` for `Jupyter Notebook`.

Comment: The procedure for Google Cloud Shell worked fine. But my existing files are not visible in the home. Anyways it helped.

Comment: Good job to answer this question. Couldn't imagine this is possible.